# How to verify the MaxSimultaneousWorkflows setting in WF

Tags: configuration, workflow-foundation

WF has a configuration property: MaxSimultaneousWorkflows - other than building a custom test app or workflow, how can you verify that the property is working?

The reason not to build a custom test app or workflow is that it doesn't tell you about the workflow that I am actually trying to verify.

*Update* The reason to verify it is to make sure it is working as Microsoft documented it when run with the workflows that will be run in production, as a way to verify there are no bugs in WF setting.

Comment: I can't help, I'm new to WF myself, but I'd like to know is why you need to.  Have you seen odd behaviour?

Comment: There has been some reports of odd behavior and someone thinks it may be related. Trying to rule it out.

Comment: I can't of any odd behavior of the top of my head. I have known people to think you cannot start more that the specified number of workflows. This is not true, it is just the number of activities that are executing at the same time. Additional activities will be queued. The ThreadPool is used so don't set it to some very high number or you will get issues with ThreadPool starvation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can explain why you need to check MaxSimultaneousWorkflows?

The purpose of the MaxSimultaneousWorkflows setting is that the default workflow scheduler uses no more than the specified number of threads for simultaneous workflow activity execution. So you can start as many worklfows as you like but only the specified number will be executing at the same time. The workflow runtime, or more accurately the DefaultWorkflowSchedulerService, does this.

So your question makes me wonder of you are trying to unit test the DefaultWorkflowSchedulerService?

Comment: Hi! i have a question: and what happens with the workflows that are waiting for execution? are they persisted or they stay in memory?

ps: sorry, my english sucks! cheers from Argentina!

Comment: At this point they stay in memory because they have activities that are ready to run. When there are no activities left to run the workflow can be removed from memory until there is new work for them to do.